# autoloading namespaced classes from a php.ini included path

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I have a class that is namespaced in a directory outside the project. The directory is included in the `include_path` directive. I want to use an `spl_autoload` class to autoload the class. But, I am only getting errors. It seems like it is only trying to load files from the project directory.

This is a windows machine, but I would like it to work on a windows or Linux machine

```
##incude_path directive##
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\Users\Joey\Dropbox\web\global_includes;C:\Users\Joey\Dropbox\web\global_includes\utility;C:\Users\Joey\Dropbox\web\global_includes\utility\arrayTools"

    //index.php
    require 'bootstrap.php';

    $array = array('Hello','world');
    $array[] = array('Hello','world','2');
    $array[2][1] = array('Hello','world',3);

    echo '<p>The number of dimesions: '.utility\arrayTools\arrayTools::numberOfDimensions($array).'</p>';

    //bootstrap.php
    spl_autoload_register('autoLoader::autoLoad');


    class autoLoader
    {
      public static function autoLoad($file)
      {
          if(is_string($file)){
              if(file_exists("$file.php")){
                  try{
                     include "$file.php";
                  }catch(Exception $exc){
                      echo '<pre><p>'.$exc->getMessage().'</p>'.$exc->getTraceAsString().'</pre>';
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yaiks, statics .. no support for namespaces .. no support for paths .. pffff ..

Comment: But it works fine if I move a copy of the folder into the project directory. So for some reason it is only check the project directories and not all of the include path directories

Comment: So I took out the static methods, and same issue. Its like it is only looking in the project folder. None of the paths from the include paths

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around it but there has to be a better way then this

```
<?php
//bootstrap.php
spl_autoload_register('autoLoader::autoLoad');

class autoLoader
{
    public static function autoLoad($file)
    {
        if(is_string($file)){
            $path_and_file = self::fileExists($file);
            if($path_and_file !== FALSE){
                include $path_and_file;
            }else{
                //This is for debugging purposes on dev only
                throw new Exception("$file Does Not exsist");
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Classes must be a string');
        }
    }

    protected static function fileExists($file)
    {
        $include_paths = explode(';',get_include_path());
        foreach($include_paths as $path){
            if(file_exists("$path\\$file.php")){
                return "$path\\$file.php";
            }elseif(file_exists(str_replace('\\','/',"$path\\$file.php"))){
                return str_replace('\\','/',"$path\\$file.php");
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

}
```